# How to optimize very large array construction with numpy or scipy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, large-data

I am processing very large data sets on python 64 bits and need some help to optimize my interpolation code.

I am used to using numpy to avoid loops but here there are 2 loops that I can't find a way to avoid.

The main problem is also that the size of the arrays I need to compute gives a Memory Error when I use numpy so I switched to scipy sparse arrays which works but takes way too much time to compute the 2 left loops...

I tried to build iteratively my matrix using numpy.fromfunction but it won't run because the size of the array is too large.

I have already read a lot of posts about building large arrays but the arrays that were asked about were too simple compared to what I have to build so the solutions don't work here.

I cannot reduce the size of the data set, since it is a point cloud that I have already tiled in 10x10 tiles.

Here is my interpolation code :

```
z_int = ss.dok_matrix((x_int.shape))

n,p = x_obs.shape
m = y_obs.shape[0]
a1 = ss.coo_matrix( (n, 3), dtype=np.int64 )
a2 = ss.coo_matrix( (3, 3), dtype=np.int64 )
a3 = ss.dok_matrix( (n, m))
a4 = ss.coo_matrix( (3, n), dtype=np.int64)

b = ss.vstack((z_obs, ss.coo_matrix( (3, 1), dtype=np.int64 ))).tocoo()

a1 = ss.hstack((ss.coo_matrix(np.ones((n,p))), ss.coo_matrix(x_obs), ss.coo_matrix(y_obs)))

shape_a3 = a3.shape[0]

for l in np.arange(0, shape_a3):
    for c in np.arange(0, shape_a3) :
        if l == c:
            a3[l, c] = rho
        else:
            a3[l, c] = phi(x_obs[l] - x_obs[c], y_obs[l] - y_obs[c])


a4 = a1.transpose()

a12 = ss.vstack((a1, a2))
a34 = ss.vstack((a3, a4))
a = ss.hstack((a12, a34)).tocoo()


x = spsolve(a, b)


for i in np.arange(0, z_int.shape[0]):
    for j in np.arange(0, z_int.shape[0]):
        z_int[i, j] = x[0] + x[1] * x_int[i, j] + x[2] * y_int[i, j] + np.sum(x[3:] * phi(x_int[i, j] - x_obs, y_int[i, j] - y_obs).T)


return z_int.todense()
```

where dist() is a function that computes distance, and phi is the following :

```
return dist(dx, dy) ** 2 * np.log(dist(dx, dy))
```

I need the code to run faster and I am aware that it might be very badly written but I would like to learn how to write something more optimized to improve my coding skills.

Comment: Another option is to continue to use the full arrays, but use memory mapping so they don't have to fit in ram.

Answer (score 0):

That code is hard to follow, and understandably slow.  Iteration on sparse matrices is even slower than iteration on dense arrays.  I almost wish you'd started with a small working example using dense arrays, before worrying about making it work for the large case.  I'm not going to try a comprehensive fix or speed up, just nibbles here and there.

This first `a1` creation does nothing for you (except waste time).  Python is not a compiled language where you define the type of variables at the start.  `a1` after the second assignment is a sparse matrix because that's what `hstack` created, not because of the previous `coo` assignment.

```
a1 = ss.coo_matrix( (n, 3), dtype=np.int64 )
...
a1 = ss.hstack((ss.coo_matrix(np.ones((n,p))), ss.coo_matrix(x_obs), ss.coo_matrix(y_obs)))
```

Initializing the `dok` matrices, `zint` and `a3` is right, because you iterate to fill in values.  But I like to see that kind of initialization closer to the loop, not way back at the top.  I would have used `lil` rather than `dok`, but I'm not sure whether that's faster.

```
for l in np.arange(0, shape_a3):
    for c in np.arange(0, shape_a3) :
        if l == c:
            a3[l, c] = rho
        else:
            a3[l, c] = phi(x_obs[l] - x_obs[c], y_obs[l] - y_obs[c])
```

The `l==c` test identifies the main diagonal.  There are ways of making diagonal matrices.  But it looks like you are setting all elements of `a3`.  If so, why use the slower sparse approach?

What is `phi`  Does it require scalar inputs?  `x_obs[:,None]-x_obs` should give a (n,n) array directly.

What does `spsolve` produce?  `x`, sparse or dense.  From your use in the `z_int` loop it looks like a 1d dense array.  It looks like you are setting all values of `z_int`.

If `phi` takes a (n,n) array, I think

```
x[0] + x[1] * x_int[i, j] + x[2] * y_int[i, j] + np.sum(x[3:] * phi(x_int[i, j] - x_obs, y_int[i, j] - y_obs).T)

x[0] + x[1] * x_int + x[2] * y_int +  np.sum(x[3:]) * phi(x_int-x_obs, y_int-y_obs).T)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! As I said, I already had a working code with dense arrays but I now need it to work for my dataset, so I switched to sparse arrays.
Phi can be modified to take arrays, I will try that. 
Also to answer you other question I use sparse matrices because they don't give any memory error whereas dense matrices do, as said in the post too.